# Show that $|f''(\xi)|\leq2$ on the actual interval.

Tags: numerical-methods

> We want to compute an approximation for $\int_{-1}^1e^{-x^2} \ dx$
>   using trapezoid method. The trapezoid rule for an interval is
>
> $$\frac{b-a}{2}(f(a)+f(b))=\int_a^bf(x)\ dx
>  +\frac{f''(\xi)}{12}(b-a)^3, \quad \xi\in(a,b).$$
>
> Show that $f''(\xi)\leq2$ on the actual interval.

The exam solutions say that

$$|f''(\xi)|=|(4x^2-2)e^{-x^2}|\leq |4x^2-2|, \tag1$$

thus $-2\le 4x^2-2 \le 2$ on $[-1,1]$.

**Questions:** Do you think this is a sufficient explanation from the lecturer? I have no idea where $4x^2-2$ came from and why $(1)$ holds to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try calculating it?

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2} [e^{-x^2}] = (4x^2 - 2)e^{-x^2}$$

Now $e^{-x^2}$ is bounded above by $1$, thus $|(4x^2 - 2)e^{-x^2}| \leq |4x^2 - 2|$, which is bounded by $2$ on the interval $[-1, 1]$.

Comment: Was just too tired/sleepy yesterday. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If
$f(x)
=e^{-x^2}
$,
then
$f'(x)
=-2xe^{-x^2}
$,
and
$f''(x)
=-(2x(-2x)+2)e^{-x^2}
=-(-4x^2+2)e^{-x^2}
=(4x^2-2)e^{-x^2}
$.